# CCXT - fetch_ohlcv function

Tags: python, ccxt

is there any way to fetch the ohlcv from active candle in kucoin(current Candle) with ccxt?
i want compare current active candle with previous closed candles.
know current candle still not closed but i need open ,high and low values from current candle.
i used this, But it did not show the information of the last candle. Other functions work the same in ccxt.
it's ↓ shows last 20 closed candles but not active candle.

```
import ccxt
import pandas

ex = ccxt.kucoin()

def ohlcv_info():
    x = ex.fetch_ohlcv('TRX/USDT', '15m', limit=20)

    df = pandas.DataFrame(x, columns=['TIME', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'VOLUME'])
    df['TIME'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['TIME'], unit='ms')
    print(f"{df}\n")
    

ohlcv_info()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick check, it seems like the last row of the df is the active candle as its close price and volume keep changing.

```py
import ccxt
import pandas
import datetime
import time

ex = ccxt.kucoin()

def ohlcv_info():
    x = ex.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT', '15m', limit=20)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(x, columns=['TIME', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'VOLUME'])
    df['TIME'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['TIME'], unit='ms')
    print(f'*** {datetime.datetime.now()} ***\n {df.tail(1)}\n')
    time.sleep(5)

for i in range(5):
    ohlcv_info()
```

```xml
*** 2023-01-21 17:17:56.808981 ***
                   TIME     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE     VOLUME
19 2023-01-21 09:15:00  22749.1  22761.3  22729.2  22731.2  15.688291

*** 2023-01-21 17:18:01.939278 ***
                   TIME     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE     VOLUME
19 2023-01-21 09:15:00  22749.1  22761.3  22729.2  22731.3  15.688842

*** 2023-01-21 17:18:07.053381 ***
                   TIME     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE     VOLUME
19 2023-01-21 09:15:00  22749.1  22761.3  22729.2  22735.1  15.806622

*** 2023-01-21 17:18:12.148174 ***
                   TIME     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE     VOLUME
19 2023-01-21 09:15:00  22749.1  22761.3  22729.2  22735.1  16.225073

*** 2023-01-21 17:18:17.243179 ***
                   TIME     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE     VOLUME
19 2023-01-21 09:15:00  22749.1  22761.3  22729.2  22735.3  16.340071
```